# string.IsNullOrEmpty to combine another directory

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I want ask to find directory name it (folder1) to combine.
But if directory not exist, i want to find another directory name it (folder2) to combine.
What should i put to it?
Here the code:

```
    public static string DataDirectory
    {

        get
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Directory))
                return null;

            return Path.Combine(Directory, "Data/folder1");

        }

    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: [Directory.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx) method.

Answer (score 2):

[Directory.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.exists.aspx) should work fine

```
public static string DataDirectory
{

    get
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Directory))
            return null;

        // Use Path.Combine just one time 
        string firstFolder = Path.Combine(Directory, "Data/folder1"); 
        if(Directory.Exists(firstFolder)
            return Path.Combine(firstFolder);
        else
            return Path.Combine(Directory, "Data/folder2");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also do something like this to first check if there are any directories, then use linq to order the directories and select the first element.

```
public static string GetDataDirectory(string root)
{
    var directoryList = Directory.GetDirectories(root);
    if (!directoryList.Any())
        return null;

    directoryList = directoryList.OrderBy(dir => dir).ToArray();
    return directoryList.First();
}
```